# HTTP validation: Combining multiple headers

Tags: validation, http, parsing, http-headers

HTTP/1.1 specification defines the following about requests with multiple header fields:

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
>      name in a message unless either the entire field value for that
>      header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]
>      or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).
>
> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field
>      name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
>      semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to
>      the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.  The order
>      in which header fields with the same field name are received is
>      therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field
>      value; a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when
>      forwarding a message.

For parsing the requests:

- Do I need to first merge the headers (separated by commas), and then validate the combined header?

or

- Do I need to validate each header separately, before combining them into one header?

or

- Is this undefined, and I can choose whatever option I like?

One example where this makes a difference, is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Upgrade: foo
Upgrade: 
Upgrade: bar
```

Here, the second individual header by itself is invalid (as the Upgrade header requires at least 1 protocol). However, the combination of all three headers becomes `foo,,bar` which is allowed.

When the specification says that it requires at least 1 of something: Is this for the full combined header, or for each header individually?

Comment: You say "`foo,,bar` which is allowed"; `Upgrade` takes comma-separated tokens, and the empty string in the middle isn't a valid token. Can you clarify what would permit this? Otherwise, both forms you give are invalid.

Comment: @Joe - see end of https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#abnf.extension

Comment: The spec says "a sender MUST NOT generate empty list elements", but suggests that servers tolerate that (not uncommon) error. For validation, rather than a real-world server, I would expect a less tolerant parse.

Comment: @Joe: It's about the server side, where the specification explicitly lists similar examples with empty list elements as allowed, as long as they are not counted toward the total number of elements.

Comment: (It's not about spec conformity of the client – I'm building the server side and want to check what is okay, and what should give a 400)

Answer (score 0):

It is for the fully combined header field. So a single "Upgrade:" without field value must be accepted (although it's illegal to send).

Comment: I clarified my answer: the empty value must be accepted by a recipient (for historic reasons), but must not be sent. Source: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#abnf.extension plus common sense...

Comment: `In contrast, the following values would be invalid, since at least one non-empty element is required by the example-list production: ""` – If it's for the fully combined header field, it's accepted. If it's per header field, it's rejected. That's what I also said in the question  ^^   If it's the combined field that counts, it's also allowed to be sent (`must not [...] unless either the entire field value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]`)

Comment: The source question was about the "it is for the fully combined header field." Rest is clear from spec.